# Multiple states sharing the same view or component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Is it possible for say two states that update a single view/component?
How do we do this in react?

```
this.state({
 dog: 'Canny'
 person: 'Brian'
})

<Text>{blank} likes beans.<Text>
```

For example, when this.state.dog updates, the field will read 'Canny likes beans', when this.state.person updates, the field will read 'Brian likes beans'. Is there a way to do this?

Edit: This is useful for the case where the view only has one window to display updates of two states, and I understand you can use a render function to achieve this, but is there a simple 'first principles' way in react to do this?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. Please, post valid code instead of pseudo-code, as it doesn't show the intention.

Comment: @estus It's hard for me to post valid code because my question is exactly asking for the right way to do it, I will try to make the question clearer though, thanks

Comment: This depends on expected logic behind this. In this example (it's `setState`, not `state`) both values will be updated. Which one should be shown? Should there be an error in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be done by introducing another state property, `personOrDog`:

```
<Text>{this.state.personOrDog} likes beans.<Text>
```

There's no straightforward way to check previous and current `person` and `dog` state to calculate `personOrDog`. Previous and current states are available in `shouldComponentUpdate` but the use of `setState` to set `personOrDog` there is discouraged because it abuses this lifecycle hook.

This means that this issue should preferably be addressed in a place where a state is updated:

```
this.setState({
  dog: 'Canny',
  personOrDog: 'Canny'
});
```

To make code DRYer, a helper can be used to set these properties, e.g.:

```
const personOrDog = (key, value) => ({
  [key]: value,
  personOrDog: value
});

...

this.setState(personOrDog('dog', 'Canny'));
```

Comment: I see, so the only way is to actually use one state to manage one datum in the view.

Comment: There is no clean way. You cannot know which one was updated last in render function without setting this expicitly. An alternative would be to update boolean state field like `isPersonUpdatedLast` instead of `personOrDog`, so it will be used like `{this.state.isPersonUpdatedLast ? this.state.person : this.state.dog}`, but that's more cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

As for me, it is usual situation for React js. Whenever you change state, innerHTML of your Text component re-renders.

```js
this.state({
 name:
 table:
})

<Text>
  Now current state.name is: {this.state.name}, current state.table: {this.state.name}
</Text>
```

PS: and don't forget to close tags: < **/** Text>

Comment: Thanks for reaching out Max, using your example, it would be how can two different states update the same blank.

<Text>
  Now current state.name/table is: {this.state.name/blank}
</Text>